# Create row or update with increment

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask SQLAlchemy and I have the following database schema:

```
Table(
  composite_primary_key,
  count INTEGER
)
```

I want to do a create or update statement where I can check if a row with a given composite primary key exists.

1. If the composite primary key is found, update the count of the row by adding something to it
2. If it isn't found, create a new row with that composite primary key and the number I have.

Is there some existing way to do this in SQLAlchemy? Something that doesn't involve writing my own query?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're using MySQL, what you need is "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..." statement see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html Unfortunately (because it's MySQL-specific), this construct is not supported by SQLAlchemy at this point so you'll have to build your own (literal) SQL query:

session.execute("INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... ")

Comment: Thanks. Like I mentioned in the question, I was looking for a SQLAlchemy way of doing it. I understand it can definitely be done with a MySQL query, but I was looking to avoid that if possible. Is it possible to prove that it can't be done with SQLAlchemy (ie some docs that say so), or is it just something one learns through experience? I understand that this is kind of a special case and it would be unlikely to be supported. I'll leave this question open for some time.